# How to combine H2 database files?

Tags: database, h2

I have multiple h2 database files (10+). Each have the exact same table structure/schema.

I want to combine all of these files to make one big h2 file.
Any ideas?

Comment: Given the amount of information you provide, there can very obviously be no universal solution. What should happen in case of ID or unique conflicts e.g.? If those cases cannot happen, some simple script for copying the data between DBs will be sufficient. Otherwise you'll need more sophisticated logic, which takes care of handling those special cases.

Comment: Sorry I should of mentioned all data is unique. What do you mean by a simple script?

Comment: That makes the process of course much easier. Have a look at http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#script (to create a dump) and http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#runscript (to import the dump). They are also available as command line tools.

Comment: That's great i'll give it a try now